# In "Real Steel" how did Charlie know the robot would run out of power?

Tags: movie, real-steel

At the end of the movie:

> Charlie Kenton (Hugh Jackman) takes control of the robot as it is put into shadow boxing mode. He then sits there and just continuously blocks, saying he is waiting for the right moment. Then by some miracle the other robot has some sort of power loss. How did he know the robot would suffer a power loss?

It might be a legitimate strategy in boxing to let your opponent wear themselves out and then to go on the offensive, but these are robots. It isn't as if robots ever get fatigued.

Comment: because he just downloaded and saw Rocky III the previous night :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because he knows Zeus' power source isn't unlimited.

This solution is a well known boxing strategy known as the "[Rope-a-dope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope-a-dope)"

> The rope-a-dope is a boxing fighting style commonly associated with Muhammad Ali in his 1974 'Rumble in the Jungle' match against George Foreman.
>
> **Technique**
>   The rope-a-dope is performed by a boxer assuming a protected stance, in Ali's classic pose, lying against the ropes, and allowing his opponent to hit him, toward the end that the opponent will tire and make mistakes which the boxer can exploit in a counter-attack. By leaning against the ropes, much of the punch's energy is absorbed by the ropes' elasticity rather than the boxer's body.

Tere's also a mention of it in [IMDB's trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433035/trivia)

> Charlie Kenton's idea to wear down Zeus's power supply by allowing him to repeatedly land blows on Atom was in fact a technique used by real life professional boxer Muhammad Ali. Nicknamed the 'rope-a-dope', Ali utilized the strategy to tire fellow boxer George Foreman, a much stronger opponent than himself, and eventually gain victory. **Ali famously angered Foreman with phrases such as "Is that all you got, George?" during the fight, mirrored in the film by Kenton's taunting hand gesture.**

This is also a technique strongly associated to Rocky Balboa, more precisely in *[Rocky III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_III)*, And there is many other link you could make between the Rocky series and Real Steal.

Comment: Not just that, they deliberately allude to this early in the film. Atom is a sparring bot, able to take many hits but deal out little damage. That's the Crux of rope a dope. It was foreshadowed from the beginning

Comment: Real Steel or Real Steal?